# Upload a Video file with current DateTime with FileName in SQL database ID Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

`YouTube_WebForm.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

public partial class YouTube_WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
       {
        BindGrid();
       }   
    }

private void BindGrid()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select ID from TBL_YouTube";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            Listviewid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Listviewid.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void uploadbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string k = FileUploadbtn.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUploadbtn.PostedFile.InputStream))
    {
        byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUploadbtn.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into TBL_YouTube(FileType, Video) values (@FileType, @Video)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",FileUploadbtn. DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString().ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileType", "video/mp4");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Video", bytes);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

`YouTube_WebForm.aspx`:

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <img src="youtube.PNG" />
                         <div>
                             <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadbtn" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" />
                             <asp:Button ID="uploadbtn" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="myButton" OnClick="uploadbtn_Click" />
                             <asp:ListView ID="Listviewid" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RepeatColumns="1" CellSpacing="15">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                            <a class="player" style="height: 150px; width: 230px; display: block" href='<%# Eval("Id", "Generic_Handler.ashx?Id={0}") %>'>
                                            </a>
                                            <u>
                                                <%# Eval("Id") %>
                                            </u>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                            <script src="FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" class="player" type="text/javascript"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                flowplayer("a.player", "FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",
                                {
                                    plugins:
                                        {
                                            pseudo:
                                                {
                                                    url: "FlowPlayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf"
                                                }
                                        },
                                    clip:
                                    {
                                        provider: 'pseudo', autoPlay: false
                                    },
                                });
                            </script>

                  </div>
           </form>
</body>
```

I have to upload a video file with current `DateTime` with `FileName` in SQL  Server database in a `ID` column. This is my code, it shows an ERROR, what will be the solution?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",FileUploadbtn.PostedFile.FileName.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString().ToString());
```

Using this line i am going to upload a video with DateTime and FileName but its Showing ERROR:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table
>   'Videos.dbo.TBL_YouTube'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: ***WHAT ERROR*** are you getting? We can't read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us** so we might be able to help you!!

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",FileUploadbtn.PostedFile.FileName.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString().ToString());                       Using this line i am going to upload a video with DateTime and FileName but its Showing ERROR :Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'Videos.dbo.TBL_YouTube'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Is you define Id as primary key?

Comment: I am not using primary Key, For varchar(MAX) can we use PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: 1. Don't use [AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). 2. Why would you use a name + date combination as the PK? Why all that hassle when there's a built-in solution?